# Which form is correct if a child won't go to school today because he has an appointment?

Tags: adjuncts

> He won't go today to school because he has an appointment.

or

> He won't go to school today because he has an appointment.

Comment: Your sentences have two differences: the position of the time adjunct *today* and the choice between the negative auxiliaries *doesn't* and *won't*.  Which would you like to ask about specifically?

Comment: the first one. the position of the time

Comment: You could use _be in school_ in place of _go to school_: _He won't be in school today because he has an appointment._ (I'm not saying _go to_ is wrong, but I think I'd be more inclined to use _be in_.)

Comment: @J.R.: that's a British/American thing. I'd be more likely to say "go to school" than "be at school", and I would never say "be in school".

Comment: @ColinFine: I'm with J.R on this one: "won't go to school" sounds like he is refusing to go. "won't be in school"  or "won't be going to school" sound like a statement of fact that he will not be present.

Answer (score 1):

These are the ways you could place "today" in this sentence:

> **Today** the child isn't going to school, because he has an appointment.
>
> The child isn't going to school **today**, because he has an appointment.
>
> The child isn't going to school, because he has an appointment **today**.

and awkwardly (but grammatically):

> The child isn't going **today** to school, because he has an appointment.

As for the difference between *doesn't* and *won't* go to school, that should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: The last one jars in my ears... - it is a weird version of the second

Comment: @mplungjan  Yes, I agree, but as far as I know it's *grammatical*.  I've heard similar expressions from time to time.

Comment: Using "the child" sounds really odd to me.

Comment: @Catija  Oh, well that's just my general indifference towards children  :D

Answer (score 0):

As @snailplane pointed out there are two differences here, where you placed "today" in the sentence, and the verb "doesn't" or "won't".

"To go to" is a verb phrase and separating it would be incorrect, so the second sentence is right.

The difference in verb choice is less about grammar than meaning, but the second sentence's "won't" is the right choice there as well. The reason is that "doesn't" means that it is a habit, he never goes to school. You could say something like the following sentence:

> He doesn't go to school because he is taught by his parents.

Comment: I don't understand why that is an excuse given to a school. In UK teaching by parents instead of school is a formal process required by law. Using that excuse here is no better than "we are on holiday".

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is not good. In the second sentence the use of "won't go" suggests the child is being [wilful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wilful) and the reason given is an excuse.

I suggest a better version of "will not go" is

> My child will not be at school today because he has an appointment.